# Roots of unity in algebraic K-theory

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras

For any commutative ring $R$, the tensor product of (finitely generated, projective) $R$-modules equips the algebraic K-theory $K(R) = K_0(R)$ with the structure of a commutative ring with unit.

For $n>2$, I'm wondering what assumptions one might need to impose upon $R$ to ensure that $K(R)$ contains primitive $n^{\rm th}$ roots of unity (i.e., a cyclic subgroup of $K(R)^{\times}$ of order $n$).  I'd even be happy with a good family of examples.

Comment: Since $K(R)^{\times}$ contains the Picard group of $R$, it is enough that the latter contains a cyclic subgroup of order $n$. There are lots of examples of this; for example, when $R$ is a regular integral finitely generated $\mathbb C$-algebra of dimension 1, whose function field is not purely transcendental over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Right, of course!  Similarly you get the same result from a positive proportion of the rings of integers of quadratic imaginary number fields, according to the Cohen-Lenstra heuristics.

Comment: (replaced earlier comment) Do you really want a cyclic subgroup of units? I bet you really want a map from $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n]$, but I doubt you'll get that.

Comment: @Ben Wieland: I guess either would make me happy, but your suggestion would make me more happy.